# How to extract this string variable in android?

Tags: java, android, string, format

```
String test=
      ["1","Low-level programming language",true],
      ["2","High level programming language",false],
      ["3","Machine language",false],["4","All of the above",false],
      ["5","None of these",false]
```

I want to separate this file like `[1","Low-level programming language",true]` and others into 5 types of string variables.

Comment: What you have shown would not compile.

Comment: What programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on a simple regex:

```
String [] splitStrings = test.split("\\],\\[");
```

You don't want to split on just comma because you only want the commas between the square brackets.

Here is a more complete example (and a regex that holds onto the brackets if you want)

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String test="[\"1\",\"Low-level programming language\",true],[\"2\",\"High level programming language\",false],[\"3\",\"Machine language\",false],[\"4\",\"All of the above\",false],[\"5\",\"None of these\",false]";
    String [] splitStrings = test.split("(?!\\]),(?=\\[)");

    System.out.println(splitStrings[0]);
    System.out.println(splitStrings[1]);
    System.out.println(splitStrings[2]);
    System.out.println(splitStrings[3]);
    System.out.println(splitStrings[4]);
}
```

Comment: i want to get only inside the value[ ]

Comment: @dellaalwin Right, that's what this should do

Comment: can u have any idea about.i want to get the second value only "Low-level programming language".Same as each statement of second value

Comment: Just split each string again on comma, and pull the second value